# Newline in code with MakeExpression

Tags: expression-manipulation, boxes

I start with

`f[x]`.

In boxes, this is

`RowBox[{"f", "[", "x", "]"}]`.

I apply `MakeExpression` to give `f[x]` again, as desired.

Then I try

`f[
x]`,

which in boxes is `RowBox[{"f", "[", "\[IndentingNewLine]", "x", "]"}]`. Applying `MakeExpression`gives `f[x]`, which is ok for my current purposes.

The problem arises when I try to apply this to `Table`. Without the newline character, eg.

`Table[x, {x, 2}]`,

converting to boxes and then using `MakeExpression` works as expected.

Then I try

`Table[x
 , {x, 2}]`.

In boxes, this is `RowBox[{"Table", "[", 
  RowBox[{"x", "\[IndentingNewLine]", ",", 
    RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"x", ",", "2"}], "}"}]}], "]"}]`

When I apply `MakeExpression` to this, I get `ErrorBox[RowBox[{"Table", "[", 
   ErrorBox[
    RowBox[{"x", "\[IndentingNewLine]", ",", 
      RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"x", ",", "2"}], "}"}]}]], "]"}]]`

Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: If the problem comes from `"\[IndentingNewLine]"`, why not just remove it? For example, `/."\[IndentingNewLine]"->Nothing//MakeExpression`

Comment: So I have tried `DeleteCases[ (My box expression here) , "[IndentingNewLine]"]`, but it didn't do anything (I feel like it should have so I was a bit unsure about this). Your code replaces it with 'Nothing', which MakeExpression still can't read properly

Comment: It seems to work for me, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem comes from the "[IndentingNewLine]", one can simply remove it. For example:

```
RowBox[{"Table", "[", 
    RowBox[{"x", "\[IndentingNewLine]", ",", 
      RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"x", ",", "2"}], "}"}]}], "]"}] /. 
  "\[IndentingNewLine]" -> Nothing // MakeExpression

(* HoldComplete[Table[x, {x, 2}]] *)
```

If you use versions early than 10.2, then this seems to work

```
DeleteCases[
 RowBox[{"Table", "[", 
   RowBox[{"x", "\[IndentingNewLine]", ",", 
     RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"x", ",", "2"}], "}"}]}], 
   "]"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", ∞]
(* HoldComplete[Table[x, {x, 2}]] *)
```

Comment: When I run your code, I get `ErrorBox[RowBox[{"Table", "[", 
   ErrorBox[
    RowBox[{"x", Nothing, ",", 
      RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"x", ",", "2"}], "}"}]}]], "]"}]] `

Comment: What version are you using? See my update.

Comment: Thanks so much, that works just great :) It appears that we only have a license for version 9 at my university

Comment: @Joe No problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression) instead?

```
ToExpression[RowBox[{"f", "[", "x", "]"}], StandardForm, Defer]
```

> f[x]

```
ToExpression[RowBox[{"f", "[", "\[IndentingNewLine]", "x", "]"}], StandardForm, Defer]
```

> f[x]

```
ToExpression[RowBox[{"Table", "[", 
RowBox[{"x", "\[IndentingNewLine]", ",", 
RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"x", ",", "2"}], "}"}]}], "]"}], StandardForm, Defer]
```

> Table[x, {x, 2}]